# How to make global math expresssion in views searchable?

Tags: views

I did manipulation calculation on webform submission data in Views by using Global Math Expression. I need to use filter of this Math Expression field, but I could not find it in the filter field. I tried to define in relationship also not available.

How can I use the global math expression in view filter?

Answer (score 0):

views doesn't allow to filter data based on computational field. In your case you are using global math function which is a calculated field.

I would suggest to use **computed_field** module and calculate your value in this field then you can easily filter your result based on this field.

Comment: I installed the computed field module, but I cannot find the field available in views. The data already submitted from webform page.